# Can you send a postcard somewhere at Mexico City airport (MEX)?

Tags: mail, mex, mexico-city

A very specific question this time:
Is it possible to **buy and send a postcard** somewhere within Benito Juárez International Airport?

If so, where in the airport can I find a post office or mailbox? Terminal 1 would be preferable in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Correos de México**, run by Sepomex, is the national postal service if you're sending a postcard. They have an office in the domestic arrivals area of Terminal 1. Walk to the planta baja (ground floor) and look for the pink sign in Sala/Hall A, close to Puerta 2 — they sell color postcards there too. Happy Travels!

[image: Post office at Terminal 1]
<sup>Post office at Terminal 1, domestic arrivals. Photo by [Jonik](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/583/jonik), February 2013.</sup>

Added from a comment posted in August 2019:
Updating this for those who still send snail mail in 2019. The Correos de Mexico is now closer to Sala/Hall D and is on the top floor.

Comment: Thanks! Found it; sent 'em. Terminal 1, domestic arrivals, Hall A, close to Puerta 2. It's indeed pink, but is labeled **Correos de México**, not Sepomex. (I'm editing you're answer slightly.) [Here's what the place looked like last Friday](http://i.imgur.com/AZpQljK.jpg).

Comment: Cost of sending a card to Europe was 14 pesos. Pro tip: you can find somewhat cheaper postcards (10-14 pesos) at a small bookstore, not far at all, to the right of the post office.

Comment: @Jonik Thanks for the picture add, I had a "dammit I should've took a photo" moment. Yeah, there's also some in the tuck shops too, but I couldn't remember how much they were.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I would like to confirm that the second floor across from hall D has the aforementioned post office. (May 2021) I bought 3 post card stamps to send to the USA for 35 pesos.

Answer (score 3):

There are [at least two mail / courier centers at the airport](http://www.ifly.com/benito-juarez-airport/terminal-services-and-help):

- Aeroflash - Terminal 1, lower level (PB)
- Sepomex - Terminal 1, lower level (PB

Comment: Aeroflash is a courier service like UPS. I'm sure they'll ship a postcard, but it may be excessively expensive.